# Can I block BetterNet VPN (Catapult Hydra) on a dd-wrt router

Tags: vpn, firewall

There is a user on **my** (home) network that keeps on exceeding their authority.  Their latest ploy is to use the Betternet VPN.

Does anyone know if - and, if so,how, I can block this VPN on my router without blocking other things.   (ie I'd prefer a default allow approach)

(Working at the command prompt is not a problem, I'm very familiar with Linux and iptables).   What I am struggling with is to find the ports / IP's / protocols it uses.   I would prefer not to block everything except http[s] for this user.

If there is a partial option - like blocking UDP but not TCP, that would be of interest as well, as would any hacks to make it harder for this user (I do not believe they have a good understanding of networking, and a friend helped them set this up)

Comment: YMMV but I feel like part of the problem is the user - if you're blocking this protocol, they may just figure out the next thing...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I am to some extent aware this might become a game of whack-a-mole, but its a mole I want to, and should be able to whack!

Comment: Would dd-wrt do something like packet capture? I used tcpdump (and wireshark would work too!) to [investigate some slightly untrusted hardware in the past](https://superuser.com/questions/1409745/tenda-mw6-mesh-is-talking-to-baidu-what-is-it-doing) and this might be an approach here. I do run a custom router (and kinda have some hardware that can be repurposed for sniffing I suspect) which makes this easier...

Comment: Betternet ports are 1194, 5228, 7268, 9110, if that helps. (though the ports they use appear to change quite often). Is there anything stopping them from using another VPN service?

Comment: @pigeonburgee - Thanks for this. I can easily  lock openvpn and pptp, and they dont have a means of buying stuff online without my/my wifes help, so its not trivial for them.

Comment: @pigeonburger - thats useful.  Does it rely on IPSec, or just use it "if it can"?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong (they used to use IPsec) - according to their FAQ, they use another protocol now called "Hydra" or "Catapult Hydra", developed by Anchorfree, which I believe is also utilised by Hotspot Shield (another free VPN), Mcafee and maybe others.