# PfSense - Squid/LightSquid report

Tags: proxy, pfsense, squid

I set up Squid/LightSquid with SSL and certs on my machines. When I open LightSquid, I get the report with the host in the URLs, **but** I also get many entries that have solely IP addresses listed and have zero bytes but with a lot of connections. Can you explain what this means?

Example:

[image: List]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably worth seeing who owns the IPs - it might be a similar situation to here https://superuser.com/questions/1409745/tenda-mw6-mesh-is-talking-to-baidu-what-is-it-doing

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The link has part of what I am thinking with some some devices just reaching out to test connectivity, etc. The other part of that post is interesting in that it could be hiding information in the sequence numbers. I've tried using reverse IP tools but the process is slow and many of the URLs don't resolve to anything. Other times it could be 1 of 15 sites that share an IP. I have seen some that appear to be run by Apple - likely it is reaching for connectivity, etc. in that instance, but many of them I just can't figure out. There are a lot of IPs being generated.