# How can I idenfity a program making network requests to unknown domain

Tags: windows, networking

I'm observing network traffic directed towards a suspicious domain . While I can't see the data being transmitted or identify the originating program, I've temporarily blocked it using the hosts file. Antivirus scans haven't revealed any malware.

Are there advanced methods to determine the type of data being sent and the program responsible for these connections?

The requests are post method and looks like this:

```
http://msdeq.com/api/v1/BFD198B962AB68555B8D480A47FC1942713C454276F4526BBFB1086DBA300436
```

Comment: You should take the appropriate steps as if you were infected with malware. The domain in question isn’t legitimate.

Comment: Its 'half' of what you're looking for, but netstat -baf run for a bit, should help you find what the originating program is. How do you know these requests are made? the tool you're using might be helpful in determining other information too. Also its http, so in theory your traffic should be in the clear

Comment: `advanced methods to determine the type of data being sent` wireshark `and the program responsible for these connections` netstat

Comment: I used charles proxy to find out these requests going out. Even with browsers, all the programs closed, I can see these requests. I used malwarebytes, but it could not detect anything. None of the services runnning looks suspicious.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek. Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to narrow down.
 [SocketHeciServer.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50059        msdeq.com:49350        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50063        msdeq.com:49350        TIME_WAIT
It looks like some Intel Process. Will investigate more on this.

Comment: @Gantendo there's also pktmon natively. When I was poking around some sus devices, I did tcpdump from my router *Unfortunately* I'm both rusty with network forensics *and* the approach I chose to only really works with my specific setup, running tcpdump from the gateway

Comment: @Sanjoy mind adding the netstat output, and the tools you used to the question? It might help with someone figuring out the other half of it.

Comment: There are free GUI tools such as Glasswire. Note that MS Windows is *continually* sending requests to Bing (e.g., news and weather), to Microsoft (crash and user data, https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/data-collection-windows), SmartScreen checks, checking for updates, etc., usw., *ad nauseam*

Comment: @JourneymanGeek. Unfortunately. since I deleted, that ping output will not work any more, I would recommend if you put your comment in answer I will mark as accepted solution. I would try to enrich my questions with additional details.

Answer (score 0):

While the details may vary - I think there's two parts to this

To identify the program that's doing this - you can use netstat. I'd go with netstat -baf (b for binary, a for all connections and listening ports, and f for FQDN), then after running it a while visually inspect which program is connecting to that domain name.

As for what data - you can use a packet filter - my router will let me run tcpdump, but something like pktmon (native to windows and already preinstalled by default)  or wireshark would be helpful. Since your connections are http, in *theory* they should be in plaintext and interpretable. While it may not be directly applicable, you can find an example of a quick analysis of [tcpdump output here](https://superuser.com/questions/1409745/tenda-mw6-mesh-is-talking-to-baidu-what-is-it-doing) - I can't imagine wireshark and/or pktmon being *too* different